# K3b fails to burn Windows ISO to DVD-R at 98% (Brasero also fails)

Tags: boot, dvd, burning, brasero, k3b

I'm trying to create a bootable Windows 8.1 ISO on a blank DVD after my system repeatedly failed to boot from a USB, only showing a flashing dash. I tried using Brasero, but I always get an error that it failed, so I tried K3b and it seems to work until it reaches 98% and than stops for about 30 seconds before displaying an error message. I tried Windows 7 ISO and the exact same thing happens. In Disks the device says: /dev/sr0 (Read-Only) I don't know if that could be the issue. The error Brasero displays is: Error while burning. SCSI error on write(0,16): See MMC specs: Sense Key 5 "Illegal request", ASC 21 ASCQ 04.

### Burned media

DVD-R Sequential

### Devices

HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH22NS50 TN02 (/dev/sr0, CD-R, CD-RW, CD-ROM, DVD-ROM, DVD-R, DVD-RW, DVD-R DL, DVD+R, DVD+RW, DVD+R DL) [DVD-ROM, DVD-R Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Jump, DVD-RAM, DVD-RW Restricted Overwrite, DVD-RW Sequential, DVD+RW, DVD+R, DVD+R Dual Layer, CD-ROM, CD-R, CD-RW] [SAO, TAO, RAW, SAO/R96P, SAO/R96R, RAW/R16, RAW/R96P, RAW/R96R, Restricted Overwrite, Layer Jump] [%7]

### System

K3b Version: 21.12.3
KDE Version: 5.91.0
Qt Version:  5.15.3
Kernel:      5.15.0-50-generic

### Used versions

growisofs: 7.1

### growisofs

Executing 'builtin_dd if=/dev/fd/0 of=/dev/sr0 obs=32k seek=0'
/dev/sr0: engaging DVD-R DAO upon user request...
/dev/sr0: reserving 2111287 blocks
/dev/sr0: "Current Write Speed" is 4.1x1352KBps.
0/4323915776 ( 0.0%) @0x, remaining ??:?? RBU 100.0% UBU   0.0%
=== last message repeated 6 times. ===
1540096/4323915776 ( 0.0%) @0.3x, remaining 1122:37 RBU 100.0% UBU  87.5%

:-( write failed: Invalid argument
/dev/sr0: flushing cache

### growisofs command:

/usr/bin/growisofs -Z /dev/sr0=/dev/fd/0 -use-the-force-luke=notray -use-the-force-luke=tty -use-the-force-luke=4gms -use-the-force-luke=tracksize:2111287 -use-the-force-luke=dao:2111287 -dvd-compat -speed=3 -use-the-force-luke=bufsize:32m

Comment: Please include OS & release details; you provide some package details but not your OS/release.

Comment: Commands like growisofs do not make bootable disks. Look at the description of it, it is for adding data to a data disk.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I tried xfburn and it managed to burn the ISO successfully. So it seems the problem was with the software.

Problem solved